# Drop Down mapping based on unique value selcetion

Tags: angularjs

> Blockquote
>   If i am selecting value 750 and 1, 750 and 2,its showing proper result its fetching data from j son as per respective selection,but in case of second selecting if i am selecting 1000 and 1 or 1000 and 2 from drop downs its not fetching the data from respective selection,its showing same as 750 and 1 or 750 and 2.

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
//Start function for filter    
app.filter('unique', function () {
     return function (input, key) {
          var unique = {};
          var uniqueList = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
               if (typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined") {
                    unique[input[i][key]] = "";
                    uniqueList.push(input[i]);
               }
          }
          return uniqueList;
     };
});
//End function for filter
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.testdata = {
          "options" : [{
                    "areaPerStorey" : 750,
                    "areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
                    "numberOfStorey" : 1,
                    "totalBuiltUpArea" : 750,
                    "totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
                    "diameterOfSteel8mm" : 8,
                    "noOfBundles8mm" : 9,
                    "weightOfBundles8mm" : 0.047,
                    "diameterOfSteel10mm" : 10,
                    "noOfBundles10mm" : 13,
                    "weightOfBundles10mm" : 0.052,
                    "diameterOfSteel12mm" : 12,
                    "noOfBundles12mm" : 7,
                    "weightOfBundles12mm" : 0.053,
                    "diameterOfSteel16mm" : 16,
                    "noOfBundles16mm" : 9,
                    "weightOfBundles16mm" : 0.057,
                    "diameterOfSteel20mm" : 20,
                    "noOfBundles20mm" : 4,
                    "weightOfBundles20mm" : 0.059,
                    "totalSteelBundlesRequired" : 42
               },
               {
                    "areaPerStorey" : 750,
                    "areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
                    "numberOfStorey" : 2,
                    "totalBuiltUpArea" : 1500,
                    "totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
                    "diameterOfSteel8mm" : 8,
                    "noOfBundles8mm" : 24,
                    "weightOfBundles8mm" : 0.047,
                    "diameterOfSteel10mm" : 10,
                    "noOfBundles10mm" : 22,
                    "weightOfBundles10mm" : 0.052,
                    "diameterOfSteel12mm" : 12,
                    "noOfBundles12mm" : 34,
                    "weightOfBundles12mm" : 0.053,
                    "diameterOfSteel16mm" : 16,
                    "noOfBundles16mm" : 8,
                    "weightOfBundles16mm" : 0.057,
                    "diameterOfSteel20mm" : 20,
                    "noOfBundles20mm" : 6,
                    "weightOfBundles20mm" : 0.059,
                    "totalSteelBundlesRequired" : 94
               },
               {
                    "areaPerStorey" : 1000,
                    "areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
                    "numberOfStorey" : 1,
                    "totalBuiltUpArea" : 1000,
                    "totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
                    "diameterOfSteel8mm" : 8,
                    "noOfBundles8mm" : 16,
                    "weightOfBundles8mm" : 0.047,
                    "diameterOfSteel10mm" : 10,
                    "noOfBundles10mm" : 16,
                    "weightOfBundles10mm" : 0.052,
                    "diameterOfSteel12mm" : 12,
                    "noOfBundles12mm" : 14,
                    "weightOfBundles12mm" : 0.053,
                    "diameterOfSteel16mm" : 16,
                    "noOfBundles16mm" : 7,
                    "weightOfBundles16mm" : 0.057,
                    "diameterOfSteel20mm" : 20,
                    "noOfBundles20mm" : 5,
                    "weightOfBundles20mm" : 0.059,
                    "totalSteelBundlesRequired" : 58
               },
               {
                    "areaPerStorey" : 1000,
                    "areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
                    "numberOfStorey" : 2,
                    "totalBuiltUpArea" : 2000,
                    "totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
                    "diameterOfSteel8mm" : 8,
                    "noOfBundles8mm" : 33,
                    "weightOfBundles8mm" : 0.047,
                    "diameterOfSteel10mm" : 10,
                    "noOfBundles10mm" : 25,
                    "weightOfBundles10mm" : 0.052,
                    "diameterOfSteel12mm" : 12,
                    "noOfBundles12mm" : 25,
                    "weightOfBundles12mm" : 0.053,
                    "diameterOfSteel16mm" : 16,
                    "noOfBundles16mm" : 24,
                    "weightOfBundles16mm" : 0.057,
                    "diameterOfSteel20mm" : 20,
                    "noOfBundles20mm" : 14,
                    "weightOfBundles20mm" : 0.059,
                    "totalSteelBundlesRequired" : 121
               },
           ],
           }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="newscript.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
   <div class = "col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 center-output " ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl" >
     <div class="row" style="margin-top:0px !important">
          <div class="col-md-12 cat-image">
               <img class="img-responsive" src='../../images/blockwork_banner.jpg'>                                   
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 step-1">
               <div class="row select-box">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <h6>Select Area</h6>
                              <select class="form-control" id="sel1"  ng-model="selectedtype" ng-options="y.areaPerStorey for (x, y) in testdata.options | unique: 'areaPerStorey' ">

                              </select>
                              <span class="arrow"></span>
                         </div> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <h6>Select Number</h6> 
                              <select class="form-control" id="sel2" ng-disabled="!selectedtype" ng-model="selectedsize" ng-options="y.numberOfStorey for (x, y) in testdata.options | unique: 'numberOfStorey' ">

                              </select>
                              <span class="arrow"></span>
                         </div> 
                    </div>  
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 step-2">

                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 step-result no-gap top-gap bottom-gap grey-box">
                         <div class="final-heading">Material Required</div>
                         <div class="col-md-12 no-gap">
                              <div class="col-md-12" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #989898;background-color: #fff;">
                                   <p><b>Total Built Up Area is</b> <span style="font-size: 16pt;color: #BD4931;margin-left: 5px;font-style: normal;">{{((selectedtype.areaPerStorey) * (selectedsize.numberOfStorey)) | number:0}}</span><span class="small-text" style="font-style: normal">Sqft</span></p>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 step-2">
                    <div class="table-responsive rebar-table-div">
                         <table class="table table-condensed rebar-table">
                              <thead>
                                   <tr class="trh">
                                        <th><b>Dia Of TMT Steel</b></th>
                                        <th><b>No Of Bundles</b></th>
                                        <th><b>Estimated Weight(MT)</b></th>
                                   </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                    
                                   <tr class="trb">
                                        <td>8 mm</td>
                                        <td><h3>{{selectedsize.noOfBundles8mm}} &nbsp;<label>Bundles</label></h3></td>
                                        <td><h3>{{(selectedsize.noOfBundles8mm * selectedsize.weightOfBundles8mm) | number : 3}} &nbsp;<label>MT</label></h3></td>
                                   </tr>

                                   <tr class="trb">
                                        <td>10 mm</td>
                                        <td><h3>{{selectedsize.noOfBundles10mm}} &nbsp;<label>Bundles</label></h3></td>
                                        <td><h3>{{(selectedsize.noOfBundles10mm * selectedsize.weightOfBundles10mm) | number : 3}} &nbsp;<label>MT</label></h3></td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr class="trb">
                                        <td>12 mm</td>
                                        <td><h3>{{selectedsize.noOfBundles12mm}} &nbsp;<label>Bundles</label></h3></td>
                                        <td><h3>{{(selectedsize.noOfBundles12mm * selectedsize.weightOfBundles12mm)| number : 3}} &nbsp;<label>MT</label></h3></td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr class="trb">
                                        <td>16 mm</td>
                                        <td><h3>{{selectedsize.noOfBundles16mm}} &nbsp;<label>Bundles</label></h3></td>
                                        <td><h3>{{(selectedsize.noOfBundles16mm * selectedsize.weightOfBundles16mm) | number : 3}} &nbsp;<label>MT</label></h3></td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr class="trb">
                                        <td>20 mm</td>
                                        <td><h3>{{selectedsize.noOfBundles20mm}} &nbsp;<label>Bundles</label></h3></td>
                                        <td><h3>{{(selectedsize.noOfBundles20mm * selectedsize.weightOfBundles20mm) | number : 3}} &nbsp;<label>MT</label></h3></td>
                                   </tr>
                              </div>
                              </div>
                              </tbody>
                         </table>

                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ng-change` for this with a controller method. Then you can trigger your filter if one of the select boxes changes.

You could probably do it with bindings but I couldn't find a way with your code.

I modified your data structure a bit because it seemed too complicated but yours would probably work as well.

Also note that there is an unbalanced tag in your html markup. (I haven't checked were it is.)

Please have a look at the demo below or this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/068jt92b/1/).

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
//Start function for filter    
app.filter('unique', function () {
     return function (input, key) {
          var unique = {};
          var uniqueList = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
               if (typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined") {
                    unique[input[i][key]] = "";
                    uniqueList.push(input[i]);
               }
          }
          
          console.log(uniqueList)
          return uniqueList;
     };
});
//End function for filter
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {

 $scope.numStoreys = [1,2];
  $scope.areaPerStorey = [750,1000];
  $scope.selectedProp = {};
 $scope.testdata = {
      "areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
          "totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
          "areaPerStorey" : [{
           size: 750,
            properties:
           [{
                    //"areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
                    "numberOfStorey" : 1,
                    "totalBuiltUpArea" : 750,
                    "diameterOfSteel8mm" : 8,
                    "noOfBundles8mm" : 9,
                    "weightOfBundles8mm" : 0.047,
                    "diameterOfSteel10mm" : 10,
                    "noOfBundles10mm" : 13,
                    "weightOfBundles10mm" : 0.052,
                    "diameterOfSteel12mm" : 12,
                    "noOfBundles12mm" : 7,
                    "weightOfBundles12mm" : 0.053,
                    "diameterOfSteel16mm" : 16,
                    "noOfBundles16mm" : 9,
                    "weightOfBundles16mm" : 0.057,
                    "diameterOfSteel20mm" : 20,
                    "noOfBundles20mm" : 4,
                    "weightOfBundles20mm" : 0.059,
                    "totalSteelBundlesRequired" : 42
               },
               {
                    //"areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
                    "numberOfStorey" : 2,
                    "totalBuiltUpArea" : 1500,
                    //"totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
                    "diameterOfSteel8mm" : 8,
                    "noOfBundles8mm" : 24,
                    "weightOfBundles8mm" : 0.047,
                    "diameterOfSteel10mm" : 10,
                    "noOfBundles10mm" : 22,
                    "weightOfBundles10mm" : 0.052,
                    "diameterOfSteel12mm" : 12,
                    "noOfBundles12mm" : 34,
                    "weightOfBundles12mm" : 0.053,
                    "diameterOfSteel16mm" : 16,
                    "noOfBundles16mm" : 8,
                    "weightOfBundles16mm" : 0.057,
                    "diameterOfSteel20mm" : 20,
                    "noOfBundles20mm" : 6,
                    "weightOfBundles20mm" : 0.059,
                    "totalSteelBundlesRequired" : 94
               }]
            }, {
             size: 1000,
             properties: [
              {
                    "numberOfStorey" : 1,
                    "totalBuiltUpArea" : 1000, // cacl size * number
                    //"totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
                    "diameterOfSteel8mm" : 8,
                    "noOfBundles8mm" : 16,
                    "weightOfBundles8mm" : 0.047,
                    "diameterOfSteel10mm" : 10,
                    "noOfBundles10mm" : 16,
                    "weightOfBundles10mm" : 0.052,
                    "diameterOfSteel12mm" : 12,
                    "noOfBundles12mm" : 14,
                    "weightOfBundles12mm" : 0.053,
                    "diameterOfSteel16mm" : 16,
                    "noOfBundles16mm" : 7,
                    "weightOfBundles16mm" : 0.057,
                    "diameterOfSteel20mm" : 20,
                    "noOfBundles20mm" : 5,
                    "weightOfBundles20mm" : 0.059,
                    "totalSteelBundlesRequired" : 58
               },
               {
                    //"areaPerStorey" : 1000,
                    //"areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
                    "numberOfStorey" : 2,
                    "totalBuiltUpArea" : 2000,
                    //"totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
                    "diameterOfSteel8mm" : 8,
                    "noOfBundles8mm" : 33,
                    "weightOfBundles8mm" : 0.047,
                    "diameterOfSteel10mm" : 10,
                    "noOfBundles10mm" : 25,
                    "weightOfBundles10mm" : 0.052,
                    "diameterOfSteel12mm" : 12,
                    "noOfBundles12mm" : 25,
                    "weightOfBundles12mm" : 0.053,
                    "diameterOfSteel16mm" : 16,
                    "noOfBundles16mm" : 24,
                    "weightOfBundles16mm" : 0.057,
                    "diameterOfSteel20mm" : 20,
                    "noOfBundles20mm" : 14,
                    "weightOfBundles20mm" : 0.059,
                    "totalSteelBundlesRequired" : 121
               },
           ]
           }]
       };
       
       $scope.updateProps = function() {
         var prop = {},
            areaPerStoreyObj = {};
  
          //$scope.selectedProp
          /*$scope.testdata = {
      "areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
          "totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
          "areaPerStorey" : [{
           size: 750,
            properties:*/
            for(var i=0; i < $scope.testdata.areaPerStorey.length; i++) {
             
              areaPerStoreyObj = $scope.testdata.areaPerStorey[i];
              console.log(i, areaPerStoreyObj, $scope.selectedtype);
              if ( areaPerStoreyObj.size == $scope.selectedtype ) {
               //console.log('props', areaPerStoreyObj
                 //.properties);
               for (var j=0; j < areaPerStoreyObj
                 .properties.length; j++) {
                 prop = areaPerStoreyObj.properties[j];
                    
                 if ( prop.numberOfStorey == $scope.selectedsize ) {
                   $scope.selectedProp = prop;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
       };
/* org dataa --> $scope.testdata = {
          "options" : [{
                    "areaPerStorey" : 750,
                    "areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
                    "numberOfStorey" : 1,
                    "totalBuiltUpArea" : 750,
                    "totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
                    "diameterOfSteel8mm" : 8,
                    "noOfBundles8mm" : 9,
                    "weightOfBundles8mm" : 0.047,
                    "diameterOfSteel10mm" : 10,
                    "noOfBundles10mm" : 13,
                    "weightOfBundles10mm" : 0.052,
                    "diameterOfSteel12mm" : 12,
                    "noOfBundles12mm" : 7,
                    "weightOfBundles12mm" : 0.053,
                    "diameterOfSteel16mm" : 16,
                    "noOfBundles16mm" : 9,
                    "weightOfBundles16mm" : 0.057,
                    "diameterOfSteel20mm" : 20,
                    "noOfBundles20mm" : 4,
                    "weightOfBundles20mm" : 0.059,
                    "totalSteelBundlesRequired" : 42
               },
               {
                    "areaPerStorey" : 750,
                    "areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
                    "numberOfStorey" : 2,
                    "totalBuiltUpArea" : 1500,
                    "totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
                    "diameterOfSteel8mm" : 8,
                    "noOfBundles8mm" : 24,
                    "weightOfBundles8mm" : 0.047,
                    "diameterOfSteel10mm" : 10,
                    "noOfBundles10mm" : 22,
                    "weightOfBundles10mm" : 0.052,
                    "diameterOfSteel12mm" : 12,
                    "noOfBundles12mm" : 34,
                    "weightOfBundles12mm" : 0.053,
                    "diameterOfSteel16mm" : 16,
                    "noOfBundles16mm" : 8,
                    "weightOfBundles16mm" : 0.057,
                    "diameterOfSteel20mm" : 20,
                    "noOfBundles20mm" : 6,
                    "weightOfBundles20mm" : 0.059,
                    "totalSteelBundlesRequired" : 94
               },
               {
                    "areaPerStorey" : 1000,
                    "areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
                    "numberOfStorey" : 1,
                    "totalBuiltUpArea" : 1000,
                    "totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
                    "diameterOfSteel8mm" : 8,
                    "noOfBundles8mm" : 16,
                    "weightOfBundles8mm" : 0.047,
                    "diameterOfSteel10mm" : 10,
                    "noOfBundles10mm" : 16,
                    "weightOfBundles10mm" : 0.052,
                    "diameterOfSteel12mm" : 12,
                    "noOfBundles12mm" : 14,
                    "weightOfBundles12mm" : 0.053,
                    "diameterOfSteel16mm" : 16,
                    "noOfBundles16mm" : 7,
                    "weightOfBundles16mm" : 0.057,
                    "diameterOfSteel20mm" : 20,
                    "noOfBundles20mm" : 5,
                    "weightOfBundles20mm" : 0.059,
                    "totalSteelBundlesRequired" : 58
               },
               {
                    "areaPerStorey" : 1000,
                    "areaPerStoreyUnit" : "sqft",
                    "numberOfStorey" : 2,
                    "totalBuiltUpArea" : 2000,
                    "totalBuiltUpAreaUnit" : "sqft",
                    "diameterOfSteel8mm" : 8,
                    "noOfBundles8mm" : 33,
                    "weightOfBundles8mm" : 0.047,
                    "diameterOfSteel10mm" : 10,
                    "noOfBundles10mm" : 25,
                    "weightOfBundles10mm" : 0.052,
                    "diameterOfSteel12mm" : 12,
                    "noOfBundles12mm" : 25,
                    "weightOfBundles12mm" : 0.053,
                    "diameterOfSteel16mm" : 16,
                    "noOfBundles16mm" : 24,
                    "weightOfBundles16mm" : 0.057,
                    "diameterOfSteel20mm" : 20,
                    "noOfBundles20mm" : 14,
                    "weightOfBundles20mm" : 0.059,
                    "totalSteelBundlesRequired" : 121
               },
           ],
           }*/

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
   <div class = "col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 center-output " ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl" >
     <div class="row" style="margin-top:0px !important">
          <div class="col-md-12 cat-image">
               <img class="img-responsive" src='../../images/blockwork_banner.jpg'>                                   
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 step-1">
               <div class="row select-box">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <h6>Select Area</h6>
                              <select class="form-control" id="sel1"  ng-model="selectedtype" ng-options="area for area in areaPerStorey" ng-change="updateProps()">

                              </select>
                              <span class="arrow"></span>
                         </div> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <h6>Select Number</h6> 
                              <select class="form-control" id="sel2" ng-disabled="!selectedtype" ng-model="selectedsize" ng-options="num 
                              for num in numStoreys" ng-change="updateProps()">

                              </select>
                              <span class="arrow"></span>
                         </div> 
                    </div>  
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 step-2">

                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 step-result no-gap top-gap bottom-gap grey-box">
                         <div class="final-heading">Material Required</div>
                         <div class="col-md-12 no-gap">
                              <div class="col-md-12" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #989898;background-color: #fff;">
                              <p><b>Total Built Up Area is</b> <span style="font-size: 16pt;color: #BD4931;margin-left: 5px;font-style: normal;">{{((selectedtype) * (selectedsize)) | number:0}}</span><span class="small-text" style="font-style: normal">Sqft</span></p>{{selectedProp}}
                              </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 step-2">
                    <div class="table-responsive rebar-table-div">
                         <table class="table table-condensed rebar-table">
                              <thead>
                                   <tr class="trh">
                                        <th><b>Dia Of TMT Steel</b></th>
                                        <th><b>No Of Bundles</b></th>
                                        <th><b>Estimated Weight(MT)</b></th>
                                   </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                    
                                   <tr class="trb">
                                        <td>8 mm</td>
                                        <td><h3>{{selectedProp.noOfBundles8mm}} &nbsp;<label>Bundles</label></h3></td>
                                        <td><h3>{{(selectedProp.noOfBundles8mm * selectedProp.weightOfBundles8mm) | number : 3}} &nbsp;<label>MT</label></h3></td>
                                   </tr>

                                   <tr class="trb">
                                        <td>10 mm</td>
                                        <td><h3>{{selectedProp.noOfBundles10mm}} &nbsp;<label>Bundles</label></h3></td>
                                        <td><h3>{{(selectedProp.noOfBundles10mm * selectedProp.weightOfBundles10mm) | number : 3}} &nbsp;<label>MT</label></h3></td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr class="trb">
                                        <td>12 mm</td>
                                        <td><h3>{{selectedProp.noOfBundles12mm}} &nbsp;<label>Bundles</label></h3></td>
                                        <td><h3>{{(selectedProp.noOfBundles12mm * selectedProp.weightOfBundles12mm)| number : 3}} &nbsp;<label>MT</label></h3></td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr class="trb">
                                        <td>16 mm</td>
                                        <td><h3>{{selectedProp.noOfBundles16mm}} &nbsp;<label>Bundles</label></h3></td>
                                        <td><h3>{{(selectedProp.noOfBundles16mm * selectedProp.weightOfBundles16mm) | number : 3}} &nbsp;<label>MT</label></h3></td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr class="trb">
                                        <td>20 mm</td>
                                        <td><h3>{{selectedProp.noOfBundles20mm}} &nbsp;<label>Bundles</label></h3></td>
                                        <td><h3>{{(selectedProp.noOfBundles20mm * selectedProp.weightOfBundles20mm) | number : 3}} &nbsp;<label>MT</label></h3></td>
                                   </tr>
                              </div>
                              </div>
                              </tbody>
                         </table>

                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
  </div>
```